# What happens for a QQuickImageResponse emitting the finished signal too early?

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2, qt-quick

In Qt6 Quick, using `QQuickAsyncImageProvider` is the recommended way to support multi-threaded asynchronous image loading, which involves implementing the `requestImageResponse` method to return a `QQuickImageResponse*` to the QML engine. The response should `emit` the `finished` signal when it has done the job (successfully or not).

In the [example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/examples/quick/imageresponseprovider?h=6.6) provided by Qt doc, the image response subclass, during the construction, builds a `QRunnable` task (which is also a `QObject`), connects the task's custom `done` signal to its custom `handleDone` slot (which would emit `finished`) and finally transfers the task to a `QThreadPool` for execution.

**My question**: is it possible that the response finishes its job very quickly and the `finished` signal is emitted before the `requestImageResponse` method returns the pointer? How is it guaranteed that the engine can catch and handle all the `finished` signals?

......On second thought, maybe it's the qt event-loop mechanism that guarantees it:

```
{
    // this may be how the engine uses the provider
    auto response = provider->requestImageResonse(...);
    // suppose now the runnable has done the job and emits "done"
    // but the signal is just queued up to the current event-loop
    // and the "handleDone" slot would not get executed
    // until the event-loop finishes handling this piece of code
    QObject::connect(r, &QQuickImageResponse::finished, ...);
    // now the response is well-connected to the engine
} 
// finally the event-loop can execute the "handleDone" slot of the response
{
    ......
    // in the image response subclass
    // void handleDone(QImage image)
    {
        this->image = image;
        emit finished();
        // the signal is guaranted to be caught by the engine 
    }
}
```

Is my guess correct?

Comment: No. While I don't have Qt experience, unfortunately, that's not how the signals/slots work: when a signal is emitted, all slots are called. If your slot isn't there then it won't be called, and Qt isn't magically holding back signals in case a matching slot is added later...

Comment: @ChristianStieber Of course signals wont be kept for slots connected in the future... actually that's exactly what i'm concerned about: how can i make sure that when the `finished` signal is emitted, it is already well connected into the qml engine? And now it seems that as long as i emit it in a slot of the response object, it will be fine, because by the time that slot is handled by qt's event loop, the response object should already be well set-up (including connecting its `finished` signal to some slot in the qml engine)